# Create XML from XSLT irrespective of input XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have just started working on XSLT and have very little experience. I have to generate/output XML as follows.

```
<A version="a" createtime="b" xmlns="abc">
<B>asd</B>
<C>gfd</C>
<D>gfrd</D>
</A>
```

In this XML all the elements/attributes and its values are hardcoded. It does not matter what is input XML, irrespective of that I have to generate above mentioned XML as output. Kindly help me...thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem? Write a template matching `/` and inside put your XML, after all, XSLT allows you to literally include any XML you want to output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stylesheet that produces your required output, regardless of the contents of the input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<A version="a" createtime="b" xmlns="abc">
<B>asd</B>
<C>gfd</C>
<D>gfrd</D>
</A>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I have misunderstood your question, then perhaps you need to explain it better?